# MATLAB matrix operation

Tags: matlab

I am having matrix with approx 3000 rows(changing) and 3 columns. 
I have count of both rows and columns. 
I am trying to plot the graph:

x=1:3000;
plot(matrix(x,1))

is there any way that I can include all rows in the plot instruction itself so that I can remove 'x=1:3000' ?

Also, I want to divide, 1st column of matrix which have 3000 rows into another matrix of 3 columns each with 1000 rows. Any specific instruction for this ? 
I have made for loop for this and then i am placing individually the elements in the new array. But its taking long time.

Comment: why not `plot(x)` or `plot(x(:,1))` or `plot(x(1:1000))`

Comment: to divide vectors use the `./` operator. Performing operations element by element in a loop is a very inefficient approach in Matlab.

Comment: hello, 
can you please explain me a bit more ? I am beginner.

Comment: If  you found my answer to be helpful, I would appreciate if you would accept it as the chosen answer. (There should be a little checkmark to the left of my answer you can click on, I say this thinking you are new, I don't mean to be condescending).

Answer (score 1):

As to the plotting issue, using the colon operator will plot all rows for your desired column:

```
plot(matrix(:,1));
```

**EDIT:** You mentioned you were a beginner. In case you haven't seen the colon operator used like this before, a colon operator all by itself when indexing into a matrix essentially means "all __", either "all rows" if in the first position or "all columns" if in the second position.

As for the second question, of splitting one column into a new matrix with multiple columns, you can use the `reshape()` function, which takes the input matrix to be reshaped and a number of output rows and columns. For example, to split the first column of `matrix` into 3 columns and put them into `newMatrix`, use the following:

```
newMatrix = reshape(matrix(:,1),[],3);
```

Note that the above code uses `[]` in the second argument (the number of rows argument) to mean "automatically determine number of rows".This is automatically determined based on the number of columns, which is defined in the third argument here as 3. The reshape function requires that the number of output rows * output columns be equal to input rows * input columns. So in the above case this will only work if the starting matrix has a number of rows which is divisible by 3.

Comment: You can let `reshape` determine the rows automagically by using `newMatrix = reshape(matrix(:,1), [], 3);`